# AppDelegate Navigation error

Tags: iphone, ios

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {   
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *str =  [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:@"mybibleapp" error:&error];
    NSLog(@"previous un");
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
    if(str != nil)
    {
      main_page *detailViewController = [[main_page alloc] initWithNibName:@"main_page" bundle:nil];
      // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
      // detailViewController.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
      [detailViewController release];
    }
```

When I put this code for navigating to main_page it shows an error that `property navigationController not found on object of appdelegate` so i put this code insted of the above

```
 main_page  *log = [[main_page alloc] initWithNibName:@"main_page" bundle:nil];
 [window addSubview:tabController.view];
 [window addSubview:log.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

the page is redirected to main_page but nothing is working in this way. no navigation in main_page is working, I cant redirect any page from the main_page. So what can I do to solve these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "proxy" viewController without nib which is loaded in MainWindow's navigationController and then do something like the following, in the proxy's viewDidLoad

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
NSString *str =  [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:@"mybibleapp" error:&error];
NSLog(@"previous un");

NSLog(@"%@", str);

UIViewController *controller;

if (!error && nil != str) {
    controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
} else {
    controller = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
}
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Comment: sir what is proxy means?i am doing a tabbar application,actually the first tabbarview is signin page second tabbarview is mainpage,so i want if the user alredy logs in it need to display the mainpage not the signin page.else it want to show the signin page

Comment: Sorry, with proxy i mean "intermediary", a go-between UIViewController to handle this thing without messing with the window or having problems like yours.

Comment: i created a proxyviewcontroller but in view diod load there is error if (nil != str) in str.

Comment: str is the name of the variable you use in your code snippet... you also have to put the variable creation code in the new viewController...

Comment: I updated my code with the variable and checking if SFHFKeychainUtils returned an error, which you didn't and so it might crash if there's something wrong with the pass

Comment: i did what u say,but always load signinpage,not the main page,if is user is already logged in then also it will navigate to the sign in page,am using tabbar app,so sigin is the first tabbar view,is this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, you are doing it all wrong. You have to have navigation controller's inside those tab bars and handle everything differently. The logic i presented you would be similar. In one case do something, in the other do something else. If you don't have any idea on how to accomplish what you want, please ask another question because is way different then what you asked here (and accept my answer if i helped you). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initial page loading is usually handled in the MainWindow.xib nib.  You shouldn't have to manually load it.

Try creating a new project from a template and then do in and look at how the appDelegate and MainWindow.xib are setup.

Comment: so there is no way to handile this navigation problm?

Comment: You need to do your view controller setup in the viewDidLoad section of the first view controller.  Something like ferostar suggested. The reason you are getting an error is because an AppDelegate does not have a navigation controller so when you call self.navigationController you are getting an error.